# Give s permission to group returns S instead

Tags: linux, permissions

When I run

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \+
```

I get

```
drwsr-S--- 10 csantos www-data   4096 Ago 30 08:31 app/
-rw-r-----  1 csantos www-data   1646 Ago 30 08:31 artisan
drwsr-S---  3 csantos www-data   4096 Ago 30 08:31 bootstrap/
-rw-r-----  1 csantos www-data   1201 Jan  7 10:17 composer.json
-rw-r-----  1 csantos www-data 111082 Jan  7 08:40 composer.lock
```

Why the command results in `S` permission and not `s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27250/uppercase-s-in-permissions-of-a-folder

> setgid is represented with a lower-case "s" in the output of ls. In
>   cases where it has no effect it is represented with an upper-case "S".

Also see: https://superuser.com/questions/509114/what-does-directory-permission-s-mean-not-lower-case-but-in-upper-case

> 'S' = The directory's setgid bit is set, but the execute bit isn't
>   set.
>
> 's' = The directory's setgid bit is set, and the execute bit is set.